# Meeting Scheduling Solution Approach

Tags: algorithm, constants, scheduling, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming

I want to develop a program to help with scheduling coaching meetings. I have looked at the knapsack problem and the nurse roster problem but I am unsure if they are the best fit for my problem. An overview of my requirements is:

(I will use sales coaching in my example)

- Staff rosters will be populated into the system from a time and attendance system (time/date).
- There will be a queue of staff who have not yet attended sales coaching
- Some of the staff are sales coachers who will chair a coaching session (one coacher per session)
- Based on the staff roster, I would like the system to generate a schedule of coaching sessions (multiple occurrences of the same session) to accommodate the queue of staff who need to attend. The logic for this schedule is based on both mandatory and optional criteria (optional chosen by user)

MANDATORY CRITERIA

(1) Each session must have a coacher, i.e. a session can't be scheduled for a time a coacher is not rostered to work

(2) Each session has a maximum capacity

OPTIONAL CRITERIA

(1) Available places on sessions are prioritized to staff in order of hire date (older staff take preference)

(2) There is a maximum threshold on the number of staff that can attend a session from a particular department (can't have 90-100% of staff from one department in a single session)

(3) There is a minimum threshold for a session (doesn't make sense for a session to be scheduled for only one person)

Obviously, I want to develop the scheduler with only the mandatory criteria first but it is important to be mindful that it will need to support the optional criteria.

I am unsure how complex this problem is although I believe it may be easier than the knapsack and nurse problems because the number of sessions can grow - I am not constrained by a finite space.

I am aware that it may not be possible for all criteria to be met for all required attendees, but I'm looking for a best fit.

Also, this system is not concerned with the actual rostering of shifts and the non-computation issues that can occur (person A does not want to work with person B, etc). As far as this system is concerned, the roster is a simple input from the T&A system.

I am in the early stages of researching this so I would appreciate advise about what I should use to solve this: nurse problem, knapsack problem, graph theory, brute force, genetic, something else? I'm basically looking for a starting point.

Thanks.

Comment: I would suggest finding a tool that solves constraint programs.

Comment: Thanks but I am developing this as a personal project to gain experience with this sort of computation. I'd rather do it myself. I have no time constraints so I have the freedom to learn.

Comment: At least you will formalize the constraints. Then later you can figure out how to solve it yourself. You'll also have a tool to verify that your solution indeed works (assuming the constraints are correct). It's a nice way to gain some experience with this sort of computation.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath Thanks for that advice - especially the part about verifying my solution works. Two queries (1) can you recommend such a tool (2) my last paragraph in the question mentions various different topics which could be used to solve the problem. I'd really appreciate advice about which one best fits my problem so I know which one to explore in greater detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn what you can from other standard problems but don't limit yourself to fit your problem in those forms. Try brute force if you like as it is sometimes useful to understand why it doesn't scale past trivial examples. I would try using one of the existing tools like optaplanner or minizinc and minion to get a feel. Definitely trying to implement your own constraint solver is very instructive if you have time. Read about how others have done this because it's not simple and there are several gotchas waiting to trap you. Also look at local search ideas as they are surprisingly easy to implement once you get your mindset right. Genetic algorithm approaches seem to be harder to get right for me at least. Good luck.